# Complete non-Archimedean field with infinite residual field

Tags: number-theory, valuation-theory

At the end of [wolfram article on non-Archimedean valuation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Non-ArchimedeanValuation.html), it is claimed that the residual field of a complete non-Archimedean field is finite. This article does not have *compactness* assumptions on $K$ or $\mathcal{O}_K$.

In **Proposition 27, p. 17** of a [notes on valued fields](https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/ashvin/files/ashvinswaminathan-juniorpaper.pdf#page27), it claims that the ring of integers is compact if and only if residual field is finite.

Is compactness condition missing in the wolfram article? Is there an example of a complete non-Archimedean field with *infinite* residual field?

Comment: The (metric) completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$, for example, ...?

Comment: The residual field of the (real) Levi-Civita field is $\mathbb{R}$. The Levi-Civita field is Cauchy complete and ordered.